# Вывести дерево данных в определенном формате

Tags: php, дерево

Есть массив:

```
    $arr = array(
     //     id  parent_id   text
    array(1,        0,      'text_1'),
    array(4,        2,      'text_4'),
    array(8,        0,      'text_8'),
    array(3,        1,      'text_3'),
    array(10,       3,      'text_10'),
    array(5,        4,      'text_5'),
    array(7,        3,      'text_7'),
    array(2,        1,      'text_2'),
    array(9,        0,      'text_9'),
    array(11,       0,      'text_11'),
    array(6,        4,      'text_6'),
    array(12,       11,     'text_12')
);
```

Необходимо сделать вывод данного массива в виде дерева в следующем формате:

```
<div>text_1
<div>text_2
    <div>text_4
        <div>text_5
            <div>text_6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Дерево у меня получилось построить А вот добавить дивы и вывести в отсортированном порядке не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста ))
Код для формирования дерева:

```
function tree(&$arr, $p_id = 0){
$out = [];
//$arr[] = asort($arr);
foreach($arr as $id => $node){
    if($node[1] == $p_id) {
        $res = ['text' => $node[2], 'parent'=> $node[1]];
        unset($arr[$id]);
        $children = tree($arr, $node[0]);
        if (count($children) > 0) $res['children'] = $children;
        $out[] = $res;
    }
}
return $out;
}

echo '<pre>';
    print_r(tree($arr));
echo '</pre>';
```

Вернет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => text_1
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => text_3
                            [parent] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => text_10
                                            [parent] => 3
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => text_7
                                            [parent] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [text] => text_8
        [parent] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [text] => text_9
        [parent] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [text] => text_11
        [parent] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => text_12
                        [parent] => 11
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function print_tree($a, $level = 0){
    foreach($a as $node){
        echo "<div class='css_$level'>";
        echo $node["text"];
        if(isset($node["children"])){
            print_tree($node["children"], $level + 1);
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

$t = tree($arr);
print_tree($t);
```

Comment: @ Mrak,  С этим деревом ф-ция возвращает ошибки ... Notice: Undefined index: text, Undefined index: children и так далее

Comment: Исправил пару ошибок